# Creating instance of an extended class from an instance of its parent

Tags: objective-c

**Some background first:**

I am extending CLBeacon in order to add some extra fields and functionality.

The header of the extended class looks like this

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface CXBeacon : CLBeacon

@property (readonly) NSString * signature;

//..... some additional methods here .....

@end
```

Then I'm using CLLocationManager to find nearby CLBeacons, etc.

The question is, since CLLocationManager's delegate methods pass in instances of CLBeacon, how do I convert those to CXBeacon? Can I just cast CLBeacon as CXBeacon and call it a day? or is there a concept that I'm missing that applies in this cases?

Answer (score 1):

Summary: subclassing `CLBeacon` will probably not do what you want.  Adding a [class category](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) might do what you want.

As you note, `CLBecaon`s are usually given to you in delegate methods, such as

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
```

This means that the `CLLocationManager` or some other apple class is actually creating `CLBeacon` instances (and not your subclass `CXBeacon` instances), and you have no control over that.

Class categories allow you to take an existing class and extend it.  To do this with `CLBeacon`, you could create `CLBeacon+MyCategoryName.{h,m}`, which you could use in the CLLocationManager delegate methods (after including "`CLBeacon+MyCategoryName.h`").

Note that there are limitations and caveats that come with categories - in your case, using a property means that you will need to implement a dynamic setter and getter (see above docs and [blogs](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/private-properties-methods-and-ivars-in-objective-c/)).

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is the sort of information I was looking for.. I just thought there might be a way to hydrate the properties of my CXBeacon with those of the original CLBeacon (using an initWithBeacon: method for example). I'll look into using categories, thanks!